# Finding duplicates by size and name using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "MyDuplicateTable" which has all the file `entries(filepath,filesize,crc32,filename)`.Now I want to find out the duplicates by size and filename.I have tried the below query for that,but it gives me only one result.
Eg:

```
 MyDuplicateTable:
    Filepath           Filesize CRC32 Filename
    c:\dup\a.txt          0       0     a.txt
    c:\dup\dup1\a.txt     0       0     a.txt
    c:\dup\b.txt          0       0     b.txt
```

Now I want to find duplicates by filename and size.Below is my query.

> ```
>  Query:"SELECT FILEPATH FROM MYDUPLICATETABLE GROUP BY FILENAME, SIZE HAVING COUNT(*)>1" Result of query:But above query returns only one record[c:\dup\a.txt]
> ```

Another query

> "Select Filepath from MyDuplicateTable where Filename
>   IN(select Filename from MyDuplicateTable GROUP BY Filename,Size HAVING
>   COUNT(*)>1)" Result of query:Above query doesnt return anything :(

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join to get the result.

```
SELECT t1.Filepath 
FORM MyDuplicateTable t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Filesize, Filename 
  FROM MyDuplicateTable 
  GROUP BY FILENAME, Filesize 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2 ON t1.Filesize = t2.Filesize AND t1.Filename = t2.Filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Filepath from MyDuplicateTable where Filename IN(select Filename from MyDuplicateTable GROUP BY Filename,Size HAVING COUNT(Filename)>1)"

Try -  count(Filename) in your having clause as above instead of count(*).